# Why do I get Invalid account data when trying to reopen a token account?

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

I am trying to unwrap SOL from a WSOL account and then initialize the token account again.

I am creating the account like so

```
   pub authority_pda: UncheckedAccount<'info>,                                                                                                                 
   #[account(                                                                                                                                                  
       init,                                                                                                                                                   
       payer = payer,                                                                                                                                          
       token::mint = mint,                                                                                                                                     
       token::authority = authority_pda,                                                                                                                       
   )]                                                                                                                                                          
   pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

To unwrap I close the account

```
 anchor_spl::token::close_account(program_unwrap_wsol_context.with_signer(&[&[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes(), &[bump]][..]]))?;
```

Then I transfer part of the unwrapped amount (didnt include code).
Then I transfer the rent amount to to the WSOL account I closed earlier.

```
anchor_lang::system_program::transfer(program_to_program_account_context.with_signer(&[&[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes(), &[bump]][..]]), account_rent)?;
```

And then I try to recreate the token account.

```
let program_open_wsol_account_context = CpiContext::new(
    ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    anchor_spl::token::InitializeAccount3 {
        account: ctx.accounts.intermediate_wsol_account.to_account_info(),
        mint: ctx.accounts.wsol_mint.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.intermediate_authority.to_account_info()
    }
);
   
anchor_spl::token::initialize_account3(program_open_wsol_account_context.with_signer(&[&[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes(), &[bump]][..]]))?;
```

Everything works except for the **initialize_account3** instruction. I get this error in the logs.

```
"Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
"Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Before initializing any account, you need to "create" it, meaning you `system_instruction::allocate` 165 bytes and `system_instruction::assign` it to the token program.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. So to clarify the allocate and assign can be invoked by anyone, ie dont need any signer seeds?

Comment: When you create an acc with system program you generate a keypair to represent that account. The private key signs, and is typically discarded after that tx. So tl;dr you shouldn't need to manually specify any additional signers.

Comment: Hello @Whiteseal, I am creating the account using a program PDA so think that I do?